# Usage of "document.getElemenentsByTagName()" in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm relatively new to html and JS. I have done my research about "document.getElementsByTagName()" but didn't understand much.

I need to do a page that has 2 headings, one combobox and 1 button. When the onclick at the button is triggered the heading must change its background color depending on the option that is chosen at the combobox and decolorize with the same technique. Here is what i 've done so far:

```js
function colorDiscolor() {
 var getButton=document.getElementById('b1');
 
 var element=document.getElementById('combo');
 var optionValue=element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
 
 if (getButton.value=="Colorize") {
  getButton.value="Decolorize";
  
  if (optionValue=="level_1") {
                        //obviously wrong
   document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  }
  else {
                       //obviously wrong
   document.getElementsByTagName('h2').style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  }
 }
 else {
  getButton.value="Colorize";
  
  if (optionValue=="level_1") {
                        //obviously wrong
   document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.backgroundColor="white";
  }
  else {
                        //obviously wrong
   document.getElementsByTagName('h2').style.backgroundColor="white";
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Ex17</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="h">
  <h1>This is h1</h1>
  <h2>This is h2</h2>
 </div>
 
 <div>
  <select id="combo">
   <option value="level_1">Level 1</option>
   <option value="level_2">Level 2</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="button" id="b1" value="Colorize"
  onclick="colorDiscolor()"/>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The answer will help me settle things in my mind about this method.
(No JQuery)
**Cheers**!

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: You should try reading the [documentation for `Document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

Comment: My question is how to use on this occasion the getElementsByTagName() to interact with the document's headings. Can't use the style.backgroundColor so what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByTagName returns a collection of elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

You need to specify index 0 to get the first, and in your case only, element.

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.backgroundColor="yellow";

Comment: Fantastic! So the logic for this method says that I need to specify indexes in order for it to work. That was really helpful! Thanks bud